# Create new Child Component within a Child Component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components, parent-child

I have an issue about creating new Components with the  `resolveComponentFactory`. First there is a `startComponent` (parent component) and from this component there are several buttons and every btn creates an new child Component. For example now I create a "childComponent" and this also works. But now I want to create an new `childComponent` within the `childComponent` and this new component shall have the `startComponent` as parent component, not the `childComponent` itself. So I Need a way to call the `addComponent()` method from the `startComponent` with my `childComponent`.

Here is the way I'm doing it at the moment:

**startComponent.ts:**

```
import {
Component, OnInit, ViewChild,
ComponentFactoryResolver,
ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

Import { childComponent } from '../childComponent/child.component';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-start',
templateUrl: './start.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./start.component.css']
})


export class startComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private dataService: DataService, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){}

ngOnInit(){}

addComponent(){

let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(childComponent);

let component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
// next Line i save the reference of the "childComponent" to a Service
// so the "childComponent" can get it and destroy himself if wanted
this.createComponentService.setReference(component, type);
}
}
```

**startComponent.html**

```
<div>
<span matTooltip="Select"><button (click)="addComponent()" class="btn">
<img class="img" src="./assets/StartIcons/childCreate-icon.png" alt="not found"> </button></span>
</div>

<div #parent></div>
```

It does work if I want to create a `childComponent` with my `childComponent`, but the `startComponent` is not the parent component then.
I hope you understand my Problem, else I can try to explain it again.

Comment: Past full startComponent.ts and .html code please.

Comment: ok, I edited the Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now I want to create an new childComponent within the
>   childComponent and this new component shall have the startComponent as
>   parent component, not the childComponent itself. So I Need a way to
>   call the addComponent() method from the startComponent with my
>   childComponent.

So, in `childComponent` you should have reference to `parentComponent(StartComponent)`. You can get it by injecting to new added childComponent:

**childComponent**:

```
constructor(private parentComp: StartComponent){

}
```

As you have reference to it, you get access to properties, methods of `parent` and within `childComponent` can call `addComponent()` easily like:

```
parentComp.addComponent();
```

### Update

Interesting, dynamically created component doesn't have parent component in `injector`. So, it can't inject parent  `StartComponent`.

### Another solution

1. Set child component's parent property with `StartComponet`:

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
      this.comps.clear();
      let aComponentFactory = 
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.compArr[0]);
      let aComponentRef = this.comps.createComponent(aComponentFactory);

      (<AComponent>aComponentRef.instance).name = 'A name';
      (<AComponent>aComponentRef.instance).parent = this;
    }
   ```

   [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-get-parent). Look at the console
2. Manually `inject` parent component in child:

   ```
   constructor(public injector: Injector ) {
       console.log('child injector', injector);
       this.parent = injector.get(AppComponent);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      console.log('parent is here', this.parent);
      this.parent.test();
   }
   ```

   [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-get-parent-manually). Look at the console

Comment: Tryed but it gives me an Error: Can't resolve all parameters for childComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).    'constructor(  private dataService: DataService, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private startComponent: startComponent)'

Comment: @Kamui, ohh. really.. It is very strange. will check

Comment: @Kamui, updated Answer. @yurzui, is it ok that dynamically created child component can't `inject` in contructor parent component? Tried to pass injector to `viewContainerRef`'s `createComponent` method. it doesn't help

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your effort and help :) But one Thing: If i compile the Code i always get an "WARNING: Circular dependencys in:..." is that sth to worry about? It works even with the warning

Comment: @Kamui, nice. I think, it's something with StackBlitz. Try in  local, should be no warnings